# How to drop voltage to give a constant DC output

Tags: voltage-divider, zener

I have a load that drives current 1.8A[Max] @26V DC.
It has to be supplied with a DC voltage of 30V[max].
I have a DC voltage 36V coming from another Power Supply Unit.

In order to supply a constant DC voltage of 30V to the load from 36V DC supply, would it be okay if I use a zener diode and a resistor as shown in the circuit or just a resistor would be sufficient?
If yes, how to choose their values to drive this load.
If not, what would be the best way to have a constant 30V DC?

I'm more concerned about the power rating.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Use a voltage regulator and preferably a buck voltage regulator so that heat dissipation is minimized.

Comment: @Andyaka Cannot find a voltage regulator that drops voltage from 36V to 30V. Buck converter needs a PWM which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid PWM - a chip will manage this for you - you don't need to control it with PWM.

Comment: If you want to go linear (no PWM) then use a pass FET with enough power dissipation for the job.  6v at 2A is 12W.  Probably that will be a TO220 plus heatsink. Then a linear regulator that supports controlling external FET (you can do it with a shunt regulator).  Look at fig 34 of the tl431 datasheet https://www.ti.com/product/TL431?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=APP-LP-null-prodfolderdynamic-cpc-pf-google-eu&utm_content=prodfolddynamic&ds_k=DYNAMIC+SEARCH+ADS&DCM=yes&gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=CjwKCAjw9vn4BRBaEiwAh0muDBi_wdxhpJTvl098pivHllAkZaUHeYwwFv1MZJ9J64lWK0YHHwP-jhoCxGsQAvD_BwE

Comment: If I use a Zener diode in series with the power supply, would it be a problem? A Zener diode which can drop 6V, gives an output of 30V from 36V supply. I thought this could be my first solution but would like to know what are the drawbacks from it @Andyaka

Comment: The reason I'm avoiding the use of buck converter is the fact that I have limitations on space@Andyaka

Comment: It only drops 6 volts when there is current flow. This of course may be fine for the load if it takes a minimum current of several mA. However, at full-load the zener would be doing the job but dissipating 10.8 watts. If that's acceptable then it's a fairly simple modification. You will of course need space around the zener to be able to dissipate the 10 watts. In fact more space than a buck regulator takes up I'll wager.

Comment: a zener isn't really meant to regulate a load, it's used as a voltage ref. you can use an adjustable voltage regulator like the LM317 to turn 36v into 30v.